# jQuery input checkbox to hide div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not sure what is happening but I am not able to make my jquery hide a div when check box is checked.  Super simple and I am not sure why it isn't working.  Thanks for the help   here is the code.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="yesall">
<div id="noshow">
content
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#yesall').change(function(){
        if (this.checked) 
            $('#noshow').fadeOut('slow');
         else {
            $('#noshow').show();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

thank you guys   I am thinking I am missing something super simple here.

Comment: Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w8hc6dvq/). Did you properly include jQuery? Any errors in console?

Comment: it is running within a mvc application cshtml file.  perhaps it nees to be in a section scripts area tag?

Comment: that was it... wow  I am an idiot.  Thanks for the help Andrew

Comment: No problem! I'm not really familiar with MVC, but I'm glad you got it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

The `$(document).ready()` function only runs once when the webpage is ready. That might be the cause of your problem. You could try:

```
   $(function(){
     $('#yesall').change(function(){
       if($(this).prop("checked")) {
         $('#noshow').show();
       } else {
         $('#noshow').hide();
     }
    });
   });
```